# Ubuntu with 2 NIC - how to forward and block traffic based on ports

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, routing

I have Ubuntu with 2 NIC:

This one is set as default gw on Ubuntu:

```
eth1, ip 192.168.10.11, gateway 192.168.10.1
```

This is set on a router, not in Ubuntu :

```
eth2, ip 192.168.20.11, gateway 192.168.20.1
```

What I'd like to do is **Route all port 119 tcp traffic to eth2** (192.168.20.11) and all other internet traffic to the eth1

I know I will need to use iptables but I wasn't able to put together a working solution yet.

Any help much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't route tcp traffic, routing is relevant to a network layer protocol or IP. You can forward or redirect IP packets based on tcp ports i.e. port forwarding. In your case you can use `iptables`. One possibility is to use rules like this

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -i eth1 -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 119 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.20.11:119
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.20.119 --dport 119 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks but maybe I didn't explain myself well. What I want to do is have all traffic to outside port 119 to go through eth2. The rules you posted look more like if my Ubuntu PC was hosting a service on port 119 but that's not the case. The service on port 119 is running somewhere on the internet.